# Different behavior when component is created via Vue.extend or via "new Vue()": view-model's data and methods not accessible if created via new Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a simple component Hello:

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'hello',
  props: {'myprop': String},
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome ' + this.myprop
    }
  },
  methods: {
    mymethod: function () {
      return 'hi there'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now, depending on how the component is created, the methods and data will be accessible.  The easiest way to illustrate is via a test, please read the comments in the test:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Hello from '@/components/Hello'

describe('Hello.vue', () => {
  it('with Vue Extend', () => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(Hello)
    const vm = new Constructor({ propsData: { myprop: 'from test via propsdata' } }).$mount()
    // following 3 expections will all SUCCEED
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.hello h1').textContent)
      .to.equal('Welcome from test via propsdata')
    expect(vm.myprop).to.equal('from test via propsdata')
    expect(vm.mymethod()).to.equal('hi there')
  })

  it('with new Vue', () => {
    const vm = new Vue(
      {
        template: "<div><hello myprop='from template in test'></hello></div>",
        components: { 'hello': Hello }
      }).$mount()
    // following expectation SUCCEDS
    expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.hello h1').textContent)
      .to.equal('Welcome from template in test')
    // following TWO expections will FAIL
    expect(vm.mymethod()).to.equal('hi there')
    expect(vm.myprop).to.equal('from template in test')
  })
})
```

How can I get the last 2 expections working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your custom component first. There are two ways to do so:

- With global registration:

  ```js
    // register
    Vue.component('hello', {
        template: "<div><hello myprop='from template in test'></hello></div>",
        // ...
    });

    // create your root instance
    const vm = new Vue({
        el: '#root' // assume root eventually renders the 'hello' component
    });
  ```

  The Vue.js docs [state that](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Registration):

  > Once registered, a component can be used in an instance’s template as a custom element […] Make sure the component is registered **before** you instantiate the root Vue instance.
- Via local registration:

  ```js
    // declare
    var hello = {
        template: "<div><hello myprop='from template in test'></hello></div>",
        // ...
    };

    // create your root instance, registering everything in 'components'
    const vm = new Vue({
        components: { 'hello': Hello }
    });
  ```

For your case, the former seems more suitable, as you want to keep SOC intact, and just test the component's functionality.

Comment: Sorry, what is SOC ?

Comment: Can you be so kind to provide the full code for test 2 in such  a way the last 2 expectations succeed. I don't see it :(

Comment: Following expectations fail in test 2:
 expect(vm.mymethod()).to.equal('hi there')
 expect(vm.myprop).to.equal('from template in test')

Comment: My point is that in TEST 2, the first expectation SUCCEEDS, so I presume that the component is mounted correctly, no? Only in test 2, expectation 2 and 3 Fail for unobvious reasons.

Comment: i honestly don't know. you're gonna have to debug your code and/or post some errors so we know what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the solution.
To get the last 2 expectations ok:

```
expect(vm.$children[0].mymethod()).to.equal('hi there')
expect(vm.$children[0].myprop).to.equal('from template in test')
```

In retrospect, quite obvious, since we add the component in a div.